# Closure of a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

Every normed space $A$ is isometrically isomorphic to a dense subset of a Banach space $B$. Is it okay for us to view $A$ as a subspace of $B$ and hence say that "the closure of $A$ is Banach", or am I abusing notation by omitting the "isometrically isomorphic" part?

Comment: Closure depends on the ambient space. If you're viewing $A\subseteq B$ then:  yes, since $A$ is a dense sub metric space of the complete metric space $B$ that works. What you **really** want to say, though, is that $A$'s *completion* is normable and hence Banach, since that doesn't depend on the initial ambient space.

Answer (score 1):

It only makes sense to talk about the closure of a subset of a topological space; you need to specify which topological space $A$ is a subset of. Just saying the closure of $A$ without any further reference means (at least to me) the closure of $A$ as a subset of $A$, whereas you are referring to the closure of $A$ as a subset of $B$. To see why this distinction needs to be made, consider the following:

> What is the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Well $\mathbb{Q}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, so the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$. On the other hand, $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has closure $\mathbb{R}$.

What you can say without any further qualification is that the *completion* of $A$ is $B$. However, saying that the completion of a normed space is a Banach space is rather tautological as a Banach space is a complete normed space by definition.